# Nested Models with separate API calls and separate stores (using custom references)

Tags: mobx-state-tree

I'm wondering what's the best practice to do two separate fetches to data that would belong to the same Model. One to get all Users data and a separate one that would request their Traits and add them to each User.

I think I could create a reference in User, to fill the data, but im not sure how to create the custom reference since it should be an array.

```
export const User = types
  .model('User', {
    id: types.identifierNumber,
    ...
    traits: types.maybeNull(TraitsbyUserReference),
  })

const TraitsbyUserReference = types.maybe(
  types.reference(Trait, {
    get(identifier: string, parent):  {
      return (parent as Instance<typeof TraitsStore>).getAllTraits()
    },
    set(value) {
      return value; // this is what doesnt work out because i'm fetching a whole array
    },
  }),
)
```

Also, is this a good practice or are there other better ways of getting this result?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of defining the model, you might try switching from `maybeNull` to an optional array with a default value in your model -

```
...
traits: types.optional(types.array(Trait), []),
...
```

As such, the model will always be instantiated with an empty traits collection.

In terms of the `TraitsbyUserReference`, I am not following what abstraction that you need with the dynamic store look-up. You could create an action (e.g. `User.actions(self => ...)`) to look-up the traits as a separate api -

```
getUserTraits(){
   /* this will vary based on your implementation of TraitsStore and how it is injected */
    const traits = self.TraitsStore.getAllTraits(self.id); 
    self.traits = traits;
}
```